# RxKotlin - Wrong subscribeOn, observeOn thread changing for Subject out of Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin-android-extensions, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I have an object that generates different strings in the random moments of time, and i need to sudscribe to this generator to take these strings and provide them to ui (maybe it will be multiple subscribers in different activities).
Suppose, i got the following code:

generator:

```
class Generator {

    private var stringToGenerate = ""

    var subject: BehaviorSubject<String> = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

    init {
        //seems like these instructions are skipped
        subject
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext { t -> Log.i("subject doOnNext", Thread.currentThread().name + " " + Thread.currentThread().id) }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map { _ -> Log.i("subject map", Thread.currentThread().name + " " + Thread.currentThread().id) }

        //imitation of async creating of strings in separate thread
        timer("timerThread", false, 2000L, 2000L) {
            stringToGenerate = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
            subject.onNext(stringToGenerate)
        }
    }
}
```

One of the activities that must consume generated strings:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        val wrongThreadObserver = object : Observer<String> {
            override fun onComplete() {
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            }

            override fun onNext(t: String) {
                Log.i("wrongThreadObserver", Thread.currentThread().name + " " + Thread.currentThread().id)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }
        }

        val generator = Generator()
        generator.subject.subscribe(wrongThreadObserver)

        //for correct work illustration
        val correctThreadObserver = object : Observer<String> {
            override fun onComplete() {
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            }

            override fun onNext(t: String) {
                Log.i("correctThreadObserver", Thread.currentThread().name + " " + Thread.currentThread().id)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }
        }

        val mainThreadSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()
        mainThreadSubject
                .doOnNext { obj -> Log.i("correctThread doOnNext", Thread.currentThread().name + " " + Thread.currentThread().id) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(correctThreadObserver)
        mainThreadSubject.onNext("test thread")
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({ mainThreadSubject.onNext("test thread 2") }, 1000)
        handler.postDelayed({ mainThreadSubject.onNext("test thread 3") }, 2000)
    }
}
```

In this case **correctThreadObserver**, created just in activity, works fine, but **wrongThreadObserver** keeps work in timer thread, it seems like it ignoring instructions **subscribeOn, ObserveOn, doOnNext** in Generator, no matter where these instuctions called - in init, in timer thread, in activity by getting object to it from generator - **wrongThreadObserver** still work in timer thread. 
So log is:

> *I/correctThread doOnNext: main 2*
>
> *I/correctThreadObserver: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 941*
>
> *I/correctThread doOnNext: main 2*
>
> *I/correctThreadObserver: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 941*
>
> *I/wrongThreadObserver: timerThread 937*
>
> *I/correctThread doOnNext: main 2*
>
> *I/correctThreadObserver: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 941*
>
> *I/wrongThreadObserver: timerThread 937*
>
> *I/wrongThreadObserver: timerThread 937*
>
> *I/wrongThreadObserver: timerThread 937*

No `doOnNext` and no main thread for `wrongThreadObserver`
What i do wrong?

Comment: Replace `subscribeOn` with `observeOn` and it should work I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the following solution: 
We must subscribe to `Observable`, not to `Subject`, so we must use the result of method `observeOn()`, not object "subject" itself.
If multiple subscribtion is needed, we can cache the result of `observeOn` in separate variable:

```
//in Generator
.......
var observableInSeparateVar = subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.......

//in TestActivity
.......
generator.observableInSeparateVar.subscribe(wrongThreadObserver)
.......
```

Also we can call `observeOn()` to subject and subscribe after that:

```
//in TestActivity
.......
generator.subject
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(wrongThreadObserver)
```